# Comparing digits in a list to an integer, then returning the digits

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am using python version 3.

For homework, I am trying to allow five digits of input from the user, then find the average of those digits.  I have figured that part out (spent an hour learning about the map function, very cool).

The second part of the problem is to compare each individual element of the list to the average, then return the ones greater than the average.

I think the "if any" at the bottom will compare the numbers in the list to the Average, but I have no idea how to pull that value out to print it.  You guys rock for all the help.

```
#Creating a list
my_numbers = [input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(5)]

#Finding sum
Total = sum(map(int, my_numbers))

#Finding the average
Average = Total/5

print ("The average is: ")
print (Average)
print ("The numbers greater than the average are: ")

if any in my_numbers > Average:
```

Comment: Just to note that `[input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(5)]` can be changed to convert to a number on input (saving using map later) - eg: `[int(input("Enter a number: ")) for i in range(5)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Creating a list
my_numbers = []
r = range(5)
for i in r:
    try:
        my_numbers.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
    except:
        print( 'You must enter an integer' )
        r.append(i)

#Finding sum
Total = sum(my_numbers)

#Finding the average
Average = Total/5
print ("The average is: ")
print (Average)
print ("The numbers greater than the average are: ")
print ([x for x in my_numbers if x>Average])
```

I'm sure that you would finally have succeeded in your code even if nobody hadn't answered.

My code is in fact to point out that you should foresee that entries could be non-integer and then to put instruction managing  errors of entry.
The basic manner here is to use `try   except`

Note the way I add `i` to `r` each time an error occurs in order to make up for the element of `r` that has been consumed.

Comment: So, the non-integers code...I don't see what the try is trying to do.  It's just trying to append the input to the list, right?  Is the little addition of (int telling it not to accept it if it's not an integer?

Comment: As soon as the instruction ``int(input("Enter a number: "))`` will have been executed without error, there will be very little chance that the appending of its result raises an error. So the ``try`` is to be sure that the transformation of the input into an integer is performed without error.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is iterate through the list and print out the numbers above the average:

```
for i in my_numbers:
    if int(i) > Average:
        print(i)
```

To make things easier, you might also want to have the `my_numbers` list actually *start out* as a list of integers:

```
my_numbers = [int(input("Enter a number: ")) for i in range(5)]
```

Now we can get rid of the `map` function (don't worry, the hour did not go to waste, you'll find it very useful in other situations as well). You could also go straight to calculating the average without calculating the total, since you won't need the total again.

```
Average = sum(my_numbers) / 5
```

This means you can change the `for` loop so that you can replace `int(i)` with `i`.

You could also create a list with a list comprehension, and then print out the values in that list.

```
aboveAverage = [i for i in my_numbers if i > Average]
for i in aboveAverage:
    print i
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I keep seeing people using "i" in these loops.  I had assumed it was just a convenient letter, but it seems like more than that.  Does it have a special function?

Comment: Also, i was trying to set the list as an int from the start, but kept getting an error.  I was putting my closing parantheses after the 5, rather than after the input.  Much obliged

Comment: @RKSiegel no, `i` is just a convention - you can replace it with anything you like. You can access it within the loop just by referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "if any" doesn't work.  Take a look at the docs for the any function to se what it does. It doesn't do what you want even if your syntax had been correct.  What you want is only the numbers greater than the average.  You could use a list comprehension: [number for number in my_numbers if number > Average].  Or you could use a loop.